# HP ProLiant 100 G5/G6/G7 Servers Series - Showing Uncorrectable ECC Events Occurred in SEL Log

Tags: wamp, wampserver

HP Insight Diagnostics Version 8.4.0.3521A (x86_64)
Computer Name: ezsetupsystem3c4a927c9e88

During Device test it gives following error

Total Memory-ECC test Failed
Description- Uncorrectable ECC Events occurred in SEL log Device, Ran on CPU 0
Recommended Repair- Please refer IPMI Sensor Event Log for ECC events
Error Code- 021278

Please help me n finding why is this error coming.
Is it because of WAMP server installation??

Answer (score 0):

This means that the server has a DIMM which has exceeded it's acceptable ECC error count. It's location is denoted in the error. Depending on the platform, you can identify the specific slot. Which HP ProLiant model is this? This is standard warranty repair.

Answer (score 0):

You have faulty memory. To identify the faulty memory run HPS Reports:
http://update.external.hp.com/HPS/HPSreports/
Once completed you have to unzip the archive an open the index.html file insite.
It will collect all hardware information and highlight in

> RED

the faulty components.